# how can i check and change the Text Of the DataBound column of My telerik RadGrid?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

in my rad grid i have a boundColumn(system.string) that i want to change it's null value to another customize text...

how can i check and change the Text Of the DataBound column of My telerik RadGrid?

thanks for your future answer

Comment: Are you trying to change the text showed on the column when the bound field to the column is null?

Comment: that is exactly that i want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this was my answer :

```
protected void grd_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;

        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataItem["Test"].Text))
        if(dataItem["Test"].Text == "&nbsp;")
        {
            dataItem["Test"].Text = "Empty";
            dataItem["Test"].ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#006E6E");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `GridBoundColumn.EmptyDataText` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gridview in the bound column there is a property called "NullDisplayText".  You can make use of this for displaying different text in place of Null.